# I love hats too, but is editing like this acceptable?

Tags: discussion, edits, winter-bash

I love hats too, but this user loves hats way too much:

In the past 10 minutes they edited 5 old posts, probably for a hat.

> [image]
>
> [image]

[Each](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10407159/revisions) [one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3145089/revisions) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9671546/revisions) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624280/revisions) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/151777/revisions) only add a few back-ticks.

Is this something that these hats are encouraging?

---

To people saying this might be improving the post or `I would have edited the same way`. Well, how about these posts?

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2025282/revisions),
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1109022/revisions),
[Three](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/151777/revisions),
[Four](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31981560/revisions),
[Five](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33492637/revisions)

These edits do nothing but add or remove a space.

(In certain contexts this might improve the edit, i.e formatting a single line of code, but clearly this isn't the case)

Comment: [Hats? People will do anything to get a hat! It'll be anarchy! Hatarchy!](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Sigh...what can you do, really?

Comment: [What's that? A hat?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_gVb3z6vtc) Sorry, I have kids

Comment: Haha just had this very [very insignificant editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26543446/revisions) on an old question

Comment: *sigh*. Despite complaints about last year's hats we have hats that while apparently encouraging good behaviour lead to less than desirable results.

Comment: Why are you so bothered?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ because large numbers of spurious actions in order to gain points or badges have historically [been a scourge on these sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) and are an active threat to the morale of those who actually contribute for the sake of contributing. Also, because every one of those actions pushes the post up for peer review, they waste an incredible amount of other people's time.

Comment: Hey! 2 more downvotes on this, and you'll have earned the Sun Wukong hat - very crafty!

Comment: -1 to help you earn the Sun Wukong hat :)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist... I gave you the hat. Ironic isn't it?

Comment: It's like the government: if you subsidize something you get more of it.

Comment: @Mogsdad Haha, was about to downvote this again but it looks like he got the hat

Comment: By this logic, isn't the Archaeologist badge 20x worse than this hat? :)

Comment: Sun Wokung? I don't remember he wore a hat.

Comment: Would the whole issue of minor edits disappear if there was a minimum edit size required to bump the post to the top of the queue? Is there any other reason that minor, useful edits should be discouraged?

Comment: @Tyler, it's a nice idea but open to abuse. A determined troll could completely overhaul a post with a series of tiny edits... unless you're saying they would still need to be reviewed, but just much later. But isn't there a timelimit for things in the queue before they automatically get acted on by Community?

Comment: Hats or not, I would have edit these posts the same way.

Comment: Did the edits make the post better even if they were only a backtick? Yes! Then what is the problem.

Comment: Won't someone think of the morale?!

Comment: If you offer hats for such things, you must assume people will bother do anything "legal" to get them.

Comment: @TobyAllen Well no, I don't think the back-ticks made the post easier to read. That's the problem with extremely small edits, they're subjective to the point where some might think it's good and some might think it's not.

Comment: I just improved a couple of seven year old posts by adding backticks to make unescaped html tags visible...

Comment: I add backticks all the time. But I also hate hats, so I do not really have anything of it.

Answer (score 39):

Do you think these edits **improve** the post? Okay, maybe they're not the most substantial... but did any harm come of the edit? Would you have rejected such an edit with this reason?

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Alright, we can admit these edits are fairly trivial. But they do make the post (albeit slightly) easier to read. *And that's the whole point of editing.* Yes, one person can make a post pristine and perfectly easy to read... but that almost never happens. Instead, you can have a series of more minor edits. Or perhaps only one or two minor edits are needed.

So are hats encouraging bad behavior? To some extent, yes. But the good they encourage also needs to be taken into account. Was it essential to edit those posts? No. But it makes them easier to read, and as a side effect, bumps the post making more people read the questions and answers.

Maybe those edits weren't essential, but they did have a net positive impact. And if that's the effect hats have overall on the site... I think they've accomplished their goal.

---

Alright, I took a second look at some of these edits (while I'm less tired than when I wrote this answer), and while they don't disgust me, they're certainly not *good*. They did slightly improve the post, but not to much of an extent. I'm really not sure there's a good way to prevent this problem -- you could add additional requirements to earning said hats, but that likely would generate *more* -- not less -- problems.

However, it is important to note that nothing *bad* came of these edits. No content was destroyed; no people were hurt. So while I don't agree with these edits, I don't disagree with them either. Winter Bash is meant to encourage positive actions (similar to badges), and while these weren't the best of edits, the hat did encourage someone who had made ~20 edits previously to make an additional 5 edits. Perhaps that's more important than whether a few edits were too minor or not.

Comment: I would have rejected the edit, and banned the user for 4 weeks. http://i.stack.imgur.com/u6PBy.jpg

Comment: Meh; I wish more people thought like you. [One of my edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10552562) is going through review right now, and it's looking like it'll be rejected. I fixed lots of bad indenting in the code that made it hard to read (example: an "if" statement being indented further than its contents), but people are marking it as "does not make the post even a little bit easier to read." It's subjective, I know, but every little really does help.

Comment: Ah; it looks like it got approved 3-2. If it was one of you, thank you!

Comment: @TwoStraws The owner of the post approved it, so it was immediately approved :)

Comment: @Rob: Ah! As good an endorsement as you can get, I guess :)

Comment: @TwoStraws Why do you add so many whitespaces at the end of a line (e.g. in the first two lines)?

Comment: @Tom Trailing whitespace wasn't visible while I was editing; it wasn't intentional.

Comment: @TwoStraws Oh ok. I see this very often and I always wonder why someone would add them, since they have no purpose.

Comment: @Tom Yeah. I recently added a plugin to Sublime that highlights trailing whitespace in hot pink – makes it much easier to spot and remove!

Comment: Note that 2 whitespaces at the end of a line is the same as `<br>`. @TwoStraws

Comment: -1 for secret reason!  *shh!*  Happy Winter Bash :)

Comment: *Do you think these edits improve the post? Okay, maybe they're not the most substantial... but did any harm come of the edit?* - Those are different things. Not harmful edits are not useful per say, and "no improvement whatsoever" is one of the reasons to reject an edit.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, but this user has 2k rep. They didn't *need* to get their edit reviewed, and they didn't need to waste anyone's time with their edit. The whole point of that reason is to a) avoid bumping posts with useless edits (pertinent to smaller sites -- Stack Overflow has hundreds of posts modified in a given period though) and b) avoid wasting reviewers' time (but that user didn't need a review for their edit, and thus wasted no time).

Comment: The fact that you have enough rep to edit without reviewing, doesn't mean that you should do those kind of edits that would otherwise be discarded. Less time wasted, but also a bad example set.

Answer (score 21):

Personally, I see nothing wrong with people editing a few old posts to get a hat, *as long as the edits leave things in better shape than before*.

Old posts don't get attention because, well, they are old. That's probably why we have a hat dedicated to this task, just like we have badges dedicated to it (Excavator, Archaeologist). If these things help old posts end up cleaner than before, what harm is there in it?

Comment: @pnuts: Beyond common sense, reaching perfection is hard. Many times while editing I ponder on the way a sentence is formed, but since I am not a native speaker I hesitate in altering it thinking that the OP might just speak in a way I do not know yet...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am a native English speaker, but I still have trouble reaching perfection in editing, because half the time while working on a lengthy edit, someone else edits before you, and you are left either having wasted your time, or else spending extra time resolving their edit with yours, or else clobbering what they've done. There's a built-in incentive to work quickly, unless the post is already starting to age (which is not the case in review, certainly).

Comment: @DanLowe: I stay away from review for this very reason, and just edit the posts I come by, taking my sweet time. I have the advantage of mostly watching the Rust tag which is still low traffic :)

Answer (score 6):

[Here's what I think](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **Hats? People will do anything to get a hat! It'll be anarchy! Hatarchy!**
>
> Worry not! All normal site rules still *apply*. If you're caught sockpuppeting for hats, you will be suspended, just as you would be normally.

Then, what's [our site rules about *editing*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) ?

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

---

Yeah...the funny part is I've just done something like that to get that hat...however **This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration**.

So have fun, **Happy new year!** <sub>(wait, too early to say that?)</sub>

---

But! don't keeping try to get all of the hats, then *It'll be anarchy!*, **have fun, move on**, but *keep this in your mind: **We're on Stack Overflow**.*

Comment: Finding 5 old posts which need much editing is easy, no need for gaming it. If you have no preference, just look into helping out with any [meta-tag:clean-up] or [meta-tag:burninate-request].

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well, that's a good idea in this case.

Comment: So the rules don't apply during the end-of-year celebration, or...?

Comment: @TylerH: Huh, what I want to say is: We're celebrating, don't because *little* things and broken the end-of-year celebration. But however, don't do *anything* to get the hats. Like *caught sockpuppeting for hats*.

Comment: @KevinGuan My comment was a little bit of a joke I admit, though I feel like your explanation is missing several key words :-)

Comment: @TylerH: What are these? You know that my English isn't good :P